# What is the gold standard for creating a main() loop that waits for a Thread in Java

Tags: java, oop, program-entry-point

I was tasked to write a small server application. It is supposed to be started via the console and then run in the background, processing some network traffic and calculating stuff locally until it receives a shutdown signal. I am pretty sure i can handle all of that - except the very basic application architecture. I am super unsure how to bring my main loop to wait for the application to finish. So here is my current code, cleaned up and omitting unnecessary parts.

```
public class TestServer {

public static Logger logger;
private static Boolean abortStartup = false;
private static ServerModule server;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Starting Server...");
        initializeServer(); //this function reads config file, and initializes all variables and stuff. If anything goes wrong, abortStartup is set to true

        if (!abortStartup) {
            runMainLoop();              
        }

        if (!abortStartup) {
            cleanup(); //clean up all initialized variables and objects
        }

    System.out.println("Goodbye.");
}


private static void runMainLoop() {
    //This is the main loop. Run this until application terminates.
    logger.log(null, "Starting main loop...", Logger.LOGLEVEL_NOTE);
        server.run();
        while (server.isAlive()) {
            //wait until server dies.
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                logger.log(null, "Interrupted during wait for main thread.", Logger.LOGLEVEL_ERROR);
            }
        }
    logger.log(null, "Done.", Logger.LOGLEVEL_NOTE);
}
```

ServerModule looks like this:

```
public class ServerModule{

public Boolean shutdown = false;
private Boolean stayAlive = true;


public ServerModule(){
    //setup everything
}

public void run() {
    //initalize timers, instantiate objects etc.. add listeners and everything. At some point, a network message will set stayAlive to false;
}

public Boolean isAlive() {
    return stayAlive;
}
```

Now for the actual question: is there a more elegant or more efficient way to go about this? i am talking about this part specifically:

```
while (server.isAlive()) {
            //wait until server dies.
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                logger.log(null, "Interrupted during wait for main thread.", Logger.LOGLEVEL_ERROR);
            }
```

Is thread.sleep okay here? Could or should i even omit it? I want to wait here at this very point of my code, so i can clean up after execution stops.

Comment: Make the thread a non-Daemon, then the program won't exit until it's finished.

Comment: Read about [BlockingQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html).

Comment: There is indeed a good number of ways you can do this. Sleeping main thread is fine if you will process requests in other threads. Alternatiely, you can have a shutdown semaphore with condition that will be signalled from elsewhere, and you will just need to wait on the condition (it will do a sleep as well, I'm pretty sure, just not as obvious, and probably better tested).

Comment: Actually, sleeping is generally a poor approach.  If you sleep for to short a time, you burn CPU cycles by busy-waiting.  If you sleep for too long a time, your some aspect of your application will be non-responsive.  There is *usually* a better way.

Comment: But there is no "gold standard" either.  (And if you say "best practice" I will report you to the thought police ... for not thinking :-) )

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, your answers were very helpful. Sadly i can only accept one answer, so i will accept the one that i am currently using in my code. Even though, the other answers tought me a lot by giving me interesting stuff to read for future projects. Thanks for answering!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make your server something ***runnable***, pack that into a Thread and join!

Example

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Thread t = new Thread(() -> {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000L);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
    System.out.println("Starting Server!");
    t.start();
    t.join();
    System.out.println("Server is done!");

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Also you can use `CountDownLatch` for your purpose, see example:

```
public class ServerModule extends Thread {
    private final CountDownLatch latch;

    ServerModule(CountDownLatch latch) {
        this.latch = latch;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000L);
            //decrease counter of the latch when job is done
            latch.countDown();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // as ctor arg use threads count for countdown
        CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
        System.out.println("Start server");
        ServerModule serverModule = new ServerModule(latch);
        serverModule.start();

        try {
            //waiting until latch count will be 0
            latch.await();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Server is done");
    }
}
```

Also with `CountDownLatch` you can create multiple server instances and waiting them in main thread until they are all done.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you're managing your threads.

At the lowest level Java thread API, your main thread can wait for the server thread to complete with:

```
serverThread.join();
```

Look at the Thread API for more options, such as putting a timeout on the `join()` (so you can take increasingly drastic measures to make it end).

Higher level threading abstractions such as `Executor`, `Future`, `ForkJoinTask` etc. give you the same ability with different APIs. A thorough exploration of these is beyond the scope of a SO answer -- Oracle has tutorials on concurrency, or there are books.